# How do you prevent pandas to_csv from formatting numbers as numeric in order to preserve leading 0s?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using the to_csv method to save a dataframe out as a csv. However, the leading 0s are being removed.

For example, this is what the dataframe looks like prior to outputting it:
[image]

And as you can see in the 6th column "Purchase Order", the data is numeric but contains leading 0s. I would like to preserve that formatting and keep the leading 0s when outputting to csv and viewing in Excel, however in the csv output the leading 0s are removed:
[image]

Is there a way to prevent this? This is the command I am using:

```
out1.to_csv(outfile + '.csv', index=False, float_format='%f')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more of an Excel issue rather than `pandas`.  If you look at your csv file with a text-editor, (I am guessing) you would still see the numbers with the leading zeroes.  I say this because I have experienced similar issues with Excel assuming the format of items within CSV files, [namely dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62665687/13386979), and producing irreversible or annoying conversions.

In this case, it looks like Excel is seeing the Purchase Order as a number, and then formatting them as such.  And it does this immediately on opening the file, so you can't go back and format the cell or anything (the zeroes are lost).

I think 2 simple alternatives would be:

- save in `.xlsx` format with `df.to_excel()`.  This worked for me with some fake-leading zeroes data.  If you only intend on using the data in Excel, maybe this is best.
- Edit your purchase order column to make it clearly text.  Like appending a non-numeric character (which could later be removed):

```
df['Purchase Order'] = '#' + df['Purchase Order']
# df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Completely agree that Excel is the culprit here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `float_format='%.16f'` or something like that?